# Error con la libreria jdbcsql.zip

Tags: sql-server

Estoy agregando la opción para SQL Server como se indica: http://jdbcsql.sourceforge.net/

y cuando lo ejecuto:

```
java -jar jdbcsql.zip -m sqlserver -h 127.0.0.1 -d dbtest -U sqluser -P ***** 'select * from table'
```

> Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile.

No se si tengo que compilarlo y que debo usar para compilarlo o importarlo en eclipse.